# Windows Ressourcemonitor and C++ Threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

when i run a C++ Programm with 2 Threads, the windows ressourcemonitor shows me more than 2 (sometimes like 20). How can it be?

Best regards

Comment: Are you debugging this program? Debugger adds a few threads, not 20, mind you, but a few. Are you using third-party components in your code that may have threads hidden deep inside? Of course you could have a bug in your code that spawns a bunch of threads. Perhaps your compiler has been subverted and now every executable you create  is secretly DDOSing some poor sucker. Far too many options, and I haven't even gotten to code ninjas yet.

Comment: On a less silly note, your development environment's debugger may help you, and if a debugger is not available, the [sysinternals suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) contains a number of tools that could give you a closer look at what is really going on. Process Monitor and Process Explorer in particular.

Comment: I'm developing in Eclipse and using MingW-64 compiler. Just created a main-method which creates a windows-thread outputting one value every second (testing). I'm using standard libraries (no external). When using just the main-method, then the monitor shows me 1 thread running. But starting the second it show abnormal counts.

Comment: If the code is short, and it sounds like it is, post it. Maybe someone will see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some windows APIs and libraries create worker threads behind the curtains. I have seen this happen using e.g audio playback and graphics APIs. It's nothing to worry about. A debugger or e.g. the free tool Process Explorer will show you some info about where the thread was created.